# JStree: how to create a child node to be the first child

Tags: jstree, children

I am trying to find a way to create a child node (with `.jstree("create", null, "inside", ....`).
But this will create a new node as the last of all existing children.

Is it possible to force to add the new node as the (new) first child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code:

```
$('#jstree').jstree(true).create_node('#', //parent node, '#' for root
          "new first node",                //data of the node
          "first"                          //position of the new node: first, last
          );
```

Also please check out the [jsTree API](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=create&f=create_node%28[obj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]%29).

HTH